# subversion 1.6 for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, svn

On official subversion site (subversion.tigris.org) it's stated that in order to install subversion in ubuntu you need to use 'apt-get install subversion'. This works, but installed version is 1.5.4. But for Windows and MacOS subversion is 1.6.2. Is it any easy and official way to install recent subversion under ubuntu?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831723/where-to-find-prebuilt-binaries-for-subversion-1-6-for-ubuntu-or-debian

Comment: There is no public key at ppa.launchpad.net/anders-kaseorg so apt-get refuses to get subversion from it. Is it normal and how to fix it ?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~anders-kaseorg/%2Barchive/subversion-1.6 tells you how to install the public key (413576CB).

Comment: Should be noted, Ubuntu 9.10 has Subversion 1.6.5 (in case anyone stumbles across this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu Backports.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports) This team of volunteers oversees the procedure for publishing new versions in existing versions of Ubuntu. In the case of subversion 1.6, a [bug has already been filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/382048). If all you want is an installable package, a few people in suggest repos containing the backport.

If you want an official Ubuntu backport of SVN, well, it's a volunteer process. I've found two other related bug reports, and I'll clean them up a bit, but ServerFault readers can help by learning the backport requirements, learning the process and making sure all the ducks are in a row, and promoting it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm spoiled by my time with other distributions, but you could also compile it from source. Download the source tar bar and then do the following:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

You could. However if you try you get a dependancy problem

The Apache Portable Runtime (APR) library cannot be found.
Please install APR on this system and supply the appropriate
--with-apr option to 'configure'

it then gives a path to get APR (and apr-utils) from svn (which is a bit short-sited, as you are just installing svn probably because you do not have it already)

if you do what it says you end up with:

....subversion-1.6.5/apr/configure: No such file or directory
configure failed for apr

Great.